# How to understand the spatial coherence of light?

Tags: optics, coherence

Can I understand spatial coherence in the following way (I'm not sure if it's correct)?

As shown in the diagram:

Each wavefront or wave surface on the left is irregular, so it is spatially incoherent.

The wavefront on the right is uniform, such as concentric circles or parallel lines, representing spatial coherence.

[image]

The temporal coherence of light is based on its spatial coherence (being spatially coherent) and having the same frequency.

temporal coherence = spatial coherence+same frequency

As shown in the diagram below, this manifests as the same color.

[image]

When I was reading the following book

[image]

I was confused about a sentence in this book about spatial coherence

On page 4 of the book,

> "An optical system employing a laser beam is spatially coherent. Thus, the signal can be described as a 2-D or 3-D complex-valued amplitude field. Spatial coherence is necessary to observe diffraction. Normal illumination (e.g., daytime) signals are not spatially coherent, so the normal illumination signal is described as a real-valued luminance in 2-D space."

Why is it said that only light with spatial coherence can be described as a 2-D or 3-D complex field? I haven't seen similar cases. Could you explain what a spatially coherent light field described by a 2-D or 3-D complex field looks like?

Comment: All light diffracts at an edge .... so I would not agree with the statement above. Coherence is more of a relative term .... the more coherent the light the better the "interference" is observed.

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram is intended to show that the wavefronts from a spatially coherent source are all concentric, spherical surfaces.* If you drew a ray diagram instead, the light rays would all be normal to the spherical wavefronts, and thus the light rays all woud appear to emanate from (or be converging on) the same, single point--the center of the spheres.

* Or, parallel, planar surfaces; but a plane arguably is the same thing as a sphere of infinite radius. If the wavefronts all are planar, then the rays in the ray diagram all must be perfectly parallel to each other.